# Facing "Missing XCode Dependency: Python Module "Six" " even after installing six

Tags: python, xcode, dart, flutter, python-module

Facing "Missing XCode Dependency: Python Module "Six" " even after installing six

```
Pip Already installed
pip install six
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages 
(1.11.0)
```

But still flutter doctor asks to install pip

```
Shivas-MacBook-Pro:Flutter shivapokala$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Mac OS X 10.13.5 17F77, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.0)
[!] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.4.1)
✗ Missing Xcode dependency: Python module "six".
  Install via 'pip install six' or 'sudo easy_install six'.
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[!] Connected devices
! No devices available
! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16428), try:

```
python2.x -m pip install six
```

or:

```
brew reinstall python@2
pip install six
```

Comment: i have done this and pip got installed but flutter showing issue with it. Not sure why...